# Same common name for multiple SSL's

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am using CentOS 7.4 and Certbot version 0.22.2

I have around 30 websites configured with Apache on single server and for them when I run command

```
sudo certbot --apache
```

it asks me for 'Which names would you like to activate HTTPS for?' and then I type in 1,2,......,30 all the number of websites.

All goes fine and it installs SSLs on all websites, but for some reason the common name for each website remains one and that is of the very first website. Is it something what we called the base domain or what? and how can we avoid it and make sure that each website name displaying on browser should also be separate?

Comment: what names are in the subject alternative name extension?

Comment: @JamesKPolk How can I check that?

Comment: using your favorite tool to look at certificates, go to the extensions section and look for the subjectAltName extension and see what's there.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Sorry for late reply, well the Subject Alternative Name looks as follows, so it contains name of all 30 sites which are on Apache:

DNS Name=websiteone.co.uk
DNS Name=websitetwo.co.uk
DNS Name=websitethree.com
DNS Name=websitefour.net
DNS Name=websitefive.com
DNS Name=www.websiteone.co.uk
DNS Name=www.websitetwo.co.uk
DNS Name=www.websitethree.com
DNS Name=www.websitefour.net
DNS Name=www.websitefive.com

Comment: Then your certificate is correct.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Yes, but you see the issued to value is same for each certificate as of very first site like webisteone.com, see here: https://ibb.co/nOCVdd

I know certificate shows padlock icon, but issued to value is same for all. How can the issued to value be different for each certificate according to its website?